# Unable to set Object in Http Interceptor Java/Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to write a code in which all i want to do is when ever a request hits the interceptor it sets the name parameter of Model Class. I am new, so  I may be doing wrong.

Model Class:

```
public class Article {

String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

Artical Service:

```
public interface ArticleService {


    String getArticleName();

    void setArticleName(String name);

}
```

ArticleServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class ArticleServiceImpl implements ArticleService {

    Article article=new Article();

@Override
public void setArticleName(String name)
{article.setName(name);

}

@Override
public void getArticleName()
{
        return article.getName();

}

}
```

InterCeptor:

```
@Component
public class MySecurityFilter extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter  {
    @Autowired
    ArticleServiceImpl articleService;




    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse  response, Object object){

     System.out.println("in interceptor");
     articleService.setArticleName("article 123");

    return true;
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    ArticleServiceImpl articleService;


    @PostMapping("/get")

    public String createNote() {


System.out.println("article name set "+ articleService.getArticleName());
return "true";


    }

}
```

All i am trying to do is call articleserviceImpl from preHandle to set article name via Article() object. Is this approach right or i am doing something else wrong.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: The question is lacking information. What is printed? What is the issue you are encountering? What is the expected behavior? What are you trying to achieve with that?